# How to release memory following use of Navigation.PushAsync() in MAUI Shell App?

Tags: memory-leaks, navigation, maui

I'm having a problem in a Shell App with memory not being released when I pop a ContentPage from the navigation stack after pushing it using Navigation.PushAsync(). Each time I create a new page, push it onto the navigation stack, pop it with the back arrow and create/push a new instance of the ContentPage, the previous ContentPages that are popped from the navigation stack stay in memory. I observe this behavior on iOS and Mac Catalyst. Observing the process in Activity Monitor, the memory use continuously increases and never decreases even if I use GC.Collect() after each push. There are no event subscriptions that would prevent objects from being destroyed.

I was able to reproduce the issue with the following simplified code that displays a long List of objects using CollectionView.

A simple class with a few properties:

```
    public class PrimaryData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }
        public string IconFileName { get; set; }

        public PrimaryData()
        {
        }
    }
```

A List of PrimaryData objects:

```
public class PrimaryDataCollection
    {
        public List<PrimaryData> Collection { get; private set; }

        public PrimaryDataCollection()
        {
            Collection = new();

            for(var i=0; i<1000; i++ ) {
                Collection.Add(
                    new PrimaryData { IconFileName = "iron_white.png", SubTitle = $"Sub{i}", Title = $"Title{i}" });
            }

        }
    }
```

and a simple ContentPage to display the List. This is in the file DisplayPrimaryCollection.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoryLeak"
             x:Class="MemoryLeak.DisplayPrimaryCollection"
             Title="Display List">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PrimaryDataCollection/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}" />
                    <Image Source="iron_white.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="30" />
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code behind that is executed everytime a button on the MainPage is pressed:

```
    private async void OnPage1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DisplayPrimaryCollection());
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Each time the button on MainPage is pressed, it displays this...

[image]

I traversed the navigation stack to verify the prior pages were indeed popped from the stack. I thought this might be a bug in MAUI and was hopeful that .NET 8 with latest MAUI workload would fix it. No such luck.

Do you see a way to force the release of memory after each page is popped? Will a different navigation strategy be much more likely to free memory? I really want to avoid changing the navigation approach because it will require a lot of rewriting of the real app that's causing me the trouble.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on the GitHub and the it relate the Collectionview memory leak. You can follow the issues up and provide the issue informaton you met.

Here are the issue threads on the GitHub you can refer to.

1. [ListView/CollectionView memory leak under Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9162)
2. [Massive memory leak in CollectionView while scrolling](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10560)
3. [[net7.0 / net8.0] [iOS] Memory leak when CollectionView.ItemsSource changes](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14664)

Comment: Thanks for the lead. After more searching, I found this bug report that is almost an exact match to my issue: [[net7.0 / net8.0] [iOS] Memory leak when the CollectionView uses CollectionChanged and when adding a CollectionView to a Page makes it and the entire page live forever #14654] (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14654) I will likely try Syncfusion's sfListView instead of CollectionView to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I tried reimplementing this using SfListView from Syncfusion instead of CollectionView. Same result. Based on some comments from MS developers, it seems the issue may be with Binding. When the page is no longer used or referenced, the object that keeps track of bound objects, might not be deleting its references to the bound objects.

Comment: It has been put into the milestones [NET 8 + Servicing, .NET 8 SR2](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/milestone/48). It will be fixed in the next update, and You can wait and follow it up.